# Creating simple database/way to store html information for user account information and generating user Profile pages

Tags: javascript, html, database, media

Code Newbie here...

So I have a page set up with a username and password box with a "create account" button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            SocialShare - Sign Up
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="logo">
            
        </div>
        <div id="logo2">
            Social<br>Share
        </div>
        <div id="usernametxt">
            Username:
        </div><input id="username">
        <div id="passwordtxt">
            Password:
        </div><input id="password"><br><br>
        <div id="security">
            For the sake of security,<br>we suggest creating a unique<BR>password specific for this site
        </div><br><br>
        <input type="button" id="submit" onclick="create()" value="Create Account"><br><br>
        <a href="">Already Have One? Log In</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know it's pretty simple and cheesy, but it's just an idea that popped up in my head.

I want to create some simple way to essentially allow me to have a place to store Usernames and passwords accessable from all different sites. There will be a Sign-up page, Login page, profile page, People page, and potentially more.

```
//LOCAL STORAGE FOR THIS PAGE
function create(){
    var un = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var pw = document.getElementById("password").value;
    localStorage.setItem('username', un);
    localStorage.setItem('password', pw);
}
```

This is the simple JavaScript for the Sign-up page.

And I know this may be asking for much, but if I do manage to set up some sort of database/storage, how might I create a code bit to properly sign people in with their specific passwords and usernames, and how do I make it so that every user will have their own page preloaded and generated with all the necessary code to make it a Profile page.

I have tried watching many youtube videos, but they are all very unclear on what goes where and there are too many third-party apps involved. It would be the greatest if I can get a super simple way to do this, and at least a better explaination on what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Sir. Pasta,

I would recommend firebase authentication. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).
Firebase authentication is beginner friendly for users that want to handle user login and signup data. They have a lot of functionality such as custom claims and user authentication for signing up. If you are familiar with node.js (or any other back-end language compatible with there system) and javascript, this should be for you.

Hope you found this helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I probably still have some learning to do with node.js and just Javascript in general, but I will definitely check this out.

Answer (score 0):

So I did something like this for a school project, I wish I had my code to show you, but sadly I lost it. I made a database with MySQL and made a user table that holds the field for password and username, and I hosted the database with MyPHPAdmin, a great program to hosts and use to create a database. Then i use HTML to make all the front end buttons and forms for the user to input their credentials. Next, I wrote PHP backend code to talk to my database to allow it to add users or check if a user has the right password when signing in. You do need to implement all the scueirty features to keep people from hacking the login, but that is the basic idea of how mine worked.

Comment: I might check out MyPHPAdmin as well, but for that, I'll also see myself needing to learn PHP. But nonetheless, it's an app on my consideration list, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this is a great way to dive in into back-end web development

Back to the question you don't want to store sensitive information if local storage.

- It's vulnerable especially if that device has multiple users
- It will get lost if they clear browser data
- Data is only present in that single device meaning if they try to login in another device it won't work.

So think of it as two separate parts
 **Front-end/client-side** this is where you have the login form and registration, basically the website the users see.

Then there's the **Back-end/server-side** this is code ran on a server and is used to communicate with the client-side and your database, (in this given situation).  It is separate from the code you have written for the front end.
 i.e (the back-end is like the guy/girl who the front end gives the form data "username" and "password" and then you can code what the back-end will do to the data before he/she takes it and hands it to the database so it can be stored.
 Inversely when you want data from the database, the back-end will get that data from the database and give it to the website for you to display to the users"

The Back-end code is not a part of your website in simpler terms it's another file ran on a server. The front end communicates with the back-end using http requests and the back-end responds with an http response.
and easy way of doing this is through the **fetch api**

 here's a code snippet on how your website might give your back-end the login data.

```
    await fetch ("http:localhost:3000/login",{
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(loginObject)
})
```

You have to write separate code for the back-end and differnt languages(python, ruby node-js, etc..) but node-js uses javascript which might make it easier if you already know JS

*"here are the user's password and username, store it"*

It's not a fact but you might wan't to use node-js as your back-end as it uses Javascript as well as for the database personally I used MongoDB as my first database and used mongoose (a framework that makes it easier to use mongoDB.

TLDR. I suggest learning

- MongoDB (For your Database)
- Express (Back-end framework for node-js for faster implantation. But learn plain old node-js as well not that different)
- NodeJS

Comment: Thanks for some explanation, it looks as though I'm just still not ready for this kind of development and have a little bit of learning to do. I'll check out these applications and play around with them for a bit to get used to them, and when I feel confident enough I'll continue onto my fun little website.